# how to play a video on ie8 browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I play this video inside ie8 browser? I think I need to use object tag, but I don't know how I can.

```
 <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" class="fillWidth-fadeIn-wow-collapse in" data-wow-delay="0.5s"
       poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/poster/Traffic-blurred2.jpg" id="video-background">
    <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/mp4/Traffic-blurred2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: are got " Your browser does not support the video tag." message in your browser ?

Comment: you don't need to say that, let the moderators mark as duplicate.

Comment: @RandomChannel - FYI, it auto-generates that message when I flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: So you are saying that you just flag as duplicate and it auto generates the sign?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML 5 tag video is fully supported in 9+ version of IE. See the especification: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp